Why does a half-bridge amplifier output half the voltage?
From a hobbyist's perspective, I can't/don't understand why the amp output voltage is only half of the supplied voltage. I am wondering if there is a trick to overcome this.

This circuit schematic above (adapted from Electrical Technology: "Half H-Bridge Inverter – Circuit, Operation, Waveforms & Uses") illustrates a half bridge amplifier where the output voltage between points A and B changes from +6 V to -6 V. My question is, "Why does it not sweep between +12 V and -12 V since the power supplied is 12?
The transistors are MOSFETs.

This question essentially asks for tuition on half bridge amplifiers, which are a well-documented technology with plenty of detailed free and high quality documentation already written on the internet to answer this question and much more. It's a Q&A site, rather than discussion forum, and can't be a personal tutorial service. I'm sure you're familiar with how the site works but refer to high-voted questions for examples of well-regarded questions. Thanks.

You need to define how output voltage is measured. What you said is true if you have bipolar supplies and the output voltage is the Peak. Drawing diagrams will often help you understand.

@TonyM You are speculating

@Mattman944 "You need to define how output voltage is measured." I guess we use a multimeter. "What you said is true if you have bipolar" if mosfet the output voltage will be ~ the equal to the supplied?

Hardly, I did just that - where do you think the rest of us learn all this stuff? Unfortunately, this question is a couple of lines that expects mountains of effort in return. Research and self-learning are paramount in decent engineering.

@TonyM asking is learning. I asked only why the output is equal to half the input i have read a lot about but as a hobbyist it is normal to be confused maybe you can help me out connects or messing points i didnt well understod ‍♂️.

(a) Again, it's a Q&A, not a discussion forum, so you're asking for tutorial on the wrong site. You're looking for an exchange that you can question and get more on - that's against the site policy. There's other sites that will give you that. (b) I sincerely and genuinely want you to make progress and succeed in engineering, on whatever scale you do it, and am advocating the best, most efficient and effective route for you to do that well. I've watched it do so with so many many people over so many many years, myself included. (cont'd)

(cont'd)... (c) All engineering is self-learning, it's such a fundamental of it, all day long. If you want to get anywhere then be reading for 95-99% self-learning. (d) You could read an answer hammered out by one of us having a go at saying it, unchecked...or (e) read a well-crafted application note, white paper, article etc, beautifully written by a dedicated and expert professional, crisp, efficient explanations revised after feedback, nicely illustrated with clear diagrams. And choose between a whole range of them, written from different povs. Who on earth would want 'd' instead of 'e'?

(cont'd)... Certainly not me, not in a million years, and I do this stuff for living, all day every day :-) The only reason left for wanting 'd' is: so you can ask questions, start a discussion with the 'teacher' who wrote it. That's the only reasonable reason left. And the site isn't for discussions or personal tutorial, which is what I started by saying. If I didn't think 'e' would get you there bestest and fastest, I wouldn't push it so strongly. Even more so at the fundamentals stages like this. It's all out there somewhere, wonderfully written and ready for you.

(cont'd)... Why base your learning on one of our (relatively) quickly-knocked-out explanations, when there's much better text, much, already written. Do yourself such a favour: search and read, learn and progress :-) I think you read my comment as a reprimand and it's so the opposite of that. I think it's also not what you wanted to hear...but it's still true. Good luck with it and enjoy.

@TonyM "you're asking for tutorial " no you should understand that I didnt studied the basics in a school, i am what you can call an autodidact and also I am not a native so you should not judge me .

You can call it something negative if you wish. But it's perfectly reasonable and necessary to assess people's actions and what they appear to be looking for when they post something on a public website and publicly ask for help. Anyway, I think you have a very thorough explanation that covers all your points plus, so I'll wish you well and leave you to it.

@Tintin, take a look at my "picture gallery" of CircuitLab schematics, especially the last one, where charged capacitors are modeled as batteries for DC Sweep Simulation to analyze their impact on the circuit's behavior.

@Tintin - Hi, (a) You broke the site rule on referencing by copying that image from elsewhere into your question, without including an appropriate reference for the source webpage e.g. website name + webpage title + URL (i.e. link). Therefore your question has been closed (again) for plagiarism. You can put it back into the review queue when you add a good reference (click "submit for review" before clicking "save edits"). (b) There's a better chance of others voting to reopen if you quote an existing appnote or similar on this topology & explain exactly what is unclear.

@SamGibson a) this was not my intention.  I will search for the page  wish me luck

@Circuitfantasist ok i will thank you

@Tintin - (a) I see you added a link, TY, but without naming the website or webpage title you copied it from, just by adding the link. That is barely enough to make it clear that you copied the schematic. It didn't clearly name the source website as I explained or as shown in the site rule. I improved that. Please do better next time. (b) Also, I see you have not included any further detail from your own research (e.g. of an existing appnote etc.) to explain exactly what is unclear e.g,. to explain why you expect the output voltage should vary between +12 V to -12 V in that circuit.

@SamGibson (a) apologize i am learning. (b) because no one did ask me for and because i thought it was obvious but i will add that now thank you Sam

"why the amp output voltage is only half of the supplied voltage?" - Its not, its -6V to 6V, which is a 12V delta, so full power supply voltage. -6V and 6V are just using a different reference point (12V/2).

”i am what you can call an autodidact” An autodidact in 2024 would do a web search and read up on whatever  subject, and in this field, install a circuit simulator and do experiments. I suggest you do the same.

@winny what about we close all the schools we dont need them we have internet and libraries , all what i have found is how it work but none has explaind why.

@WesleyLee what you are refering at is peak to peak but remember the topology uses two transistors so it should swing 12v <=> -12v.

I'm not refering to peak to peak, and transistor count has nothing to do with it.. I'm just reminding you to pay attention to the voltage references. If you have 0 to 12V and one end of the load is at 6V, there is no way you can get +12V or -12V on your load by connecting the other side of the load to 0V or 12V(no matter how many transistors you use to do it).

Let me put it this way: you have a 12cm ruler and you put a screw at the 6cm mark. Doesnt matter where you put another screw in the ruler its never going to be 12cm away..

@Tintin An autodidact like yourself does not need schools. It’s the very definition of the word. How’s the simulator installation coming along?

@WesleyLee "(no matter how many transistors you use to do it). "  what about full bridge also known as H bridge?    "you have a 12cm ruler " example how much voltage is passing throught the transistor(screw).

Voltage isn’t passing though anything, current is. Voltage is always across.

@Tintin - If you put one side of your load fixed at 6V then by definition its not a full bridge.

You've labelled the potentials at either terminal of the voltage source as 0V and +12V, so in keeping with those, all potentials I quote will be with respect to the 0V node.
Node B has a potential controlled by the transistors, and will lie somewhere between \$V_B=0V\$ and \$V_B=+12V\$, depending on the state of the transistors.
There is a caveat to my next claim; the capacitor divider holds node A at half-way between the supplies, so \$V_A = +6V\$. The caveat is that the capacitors will charge or discharge, and \$V_A\$ will therefore change.
The capacitors charge and discharge via load \$R_L\$, and thus \$V_A\$ will vary at a rate heavily dependent on the time constant \$R_L \times C\$. Without negative feedback to control the transistors, and endow them with near zero output impedance, transistor channel resistance will also play a role.
In any case, the claim that \$V_A=+6V\$ is therefore only valid if the frequency of the voltage signal at B is high enough that variations of \$V_A\$ are negligible. Under this condition, where \$V_A\$ remains approximately constant at \$V_A=+6V\$, the potential difference \$V_B-V_A\$ across \$R_L\$ will be constrained as follows.
When \$V_B=0V\$:
$$ V_B - V_A = 0V - (+6V) = -6V $$
When \$V_B=+12V\$:
$$ V_B - V_A = (+12V) - (+6V) = +6V $$
Therefore, at frequency, the voltage across the load will vary between -6V and +6V. Note the italicised word "across", to indicate that this is a potential difference, not an absolute potential.

It is worth considering the consequences of an extremely low frequency of signal at B. If given a long enough time to charge/discharge, then the above treatment will not be appropriate. For instance, if B is held at \$V_B=0V\$ for a long time, much longer than \$R_L \times C\$, eventually the upper capacitor will charge to the full 12V potential difference, and the lower capacitor will discharge completely, to 0V. Therefore \$V_A=0V\$.
Then, immediately following a transition to \$V_B=+12V\$, and before \$V_A\$ has time to change, the potential difference across the load will be:
$$ V_B - V_A = (+12V) - 0V = +12V $$
Now, with B held at a fixed \$V_B=+12V\$ for a long time, the capacitors will charge/discharge to produce the state \$V_A=+12V\$ also. Then, following a transition to \$V_B=0V\$, the load will suddenly have this voltage across it:
$$ V_B - V_A = 0V - (+12V) = -12V $$
This means that the voltage across \$R_L\$ varies between +12V and −12V, twice as far as with a high frequency signal at B.

This behaviour is easy to observe in a simulation:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Voltage source V1 is a square wave representing the source of potential at B set by the transistors. It varies between 0V and +12V as you would expect from those transistors, and at high frequency (1kHz), this is the behaviour of the system:

You can see \$V_A\$ (orange) varying only very slightly, and the load voltage \$V_B-V_A\$ (brown) goes between ±6V.
This is what happens when V1's frequency is low enough (2Hz) that the capacitors are able to charge/discharge almost completely within one cycle:

The main features to note here are:

The charge/discharge curves are clearly visible
\$V_A\$ is no longer constant, since the capacitors have ample time to charge/discharge before input \$V_B\$ changes state
Load voltage (brown) reaches nearly +12V and −12V
Load waveform is no longer a good reproduction of the input


The problem with this design is the use of capacitors to hold A somewhere near +6V. With a fixed potential at A, the voltage across \$R_L\$ can't have a greater amplitude than the signal at B.
If you need a peak-to-peak voltage of 24V across the load (without using a 24V suppy), regardless of frequency, then you must control potential, explicitly, at both ends of \$R_L\$. That is, when \$V_B=+12V\$, then you require \$V_A=0V\$, and vice versa.
This requires replacing the capacitors with another push-pull pair, making the system a full H-bridge, not a half-bridge:

simulate this circuit
CircuitLab doesn't have IGBT symbols, Q1 to Q4 are supposed to be IGBTs. Q1 and Q2 explicitly set \$V_A\$, while Q3 and Q4 control \$V_B\$ as before.
If you arrange things such that \$0V < V_B < 12V\$, and \$V_A = +12V - V_B\$ (both therefore lying between 0V and +12V), then you have this voltage across \$R_L\$:
$$ V_{RL} = V_B - V_A = V_B - (+12V - V_B) = 2V_B - 12V $$
That's a potential difference varying between −12V and +12V (24V peak-to-peak) for \$V_B\$ going between 0V and +12V (12V peak-to peak).

Simon thank you for the long answer but we are going to agree that the half bridge topology doesnt have a frequency limitation and that it is the transistor what limit frequency, and another remarque in your circuit the capacitors were non polarised with a high capacity 1mF so

@Tintin So what?

@Tintin I've explained why the half bridge won't provide more than 12V pk-pk across the load, why the capacitors might cause more than 12V pk-pk, and how to produce 24V pk-pk across the load. All your questions answered.

Simon the word "Claim" is confusing, in the firstS paragraph of your answer i felt like you did compared the half bridge to a relaxation oscillator, then you did bring the effect of frequency here you lost me because i know that half bridge are not affected by frequency. Anyway so +-6 has to do with the capacitors is that what you are saying?

@Tintin In your circuit above, fix C to whatever value you’d like and drop the switching frequency to say 0.1 Hz. Does it behave the same as for 10 kHz? If not, it’s frequency dependent.

@winny what about 0.01 Hz?

@Tintin What effect did it have?

Here is what a half-bridge amplifier output might look like. The peak voltage at the output will be V. A multimeter will measure RMS or an approximation of RMS.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Mattman let assume that +V is 12v and -V is 0(ground) the speaker or where the arrow is indicating  is oscillating between +6v and -6 isnt? Why not +12v and -12v ?

@Tintin In that scenario the speaker would see +12 V and 0 V at the extremes and would be very unhappy due to the DC average current in the coil.  If AC coupled, there would be no DC current, but then the capacitor's average voltage would be half the supply limiting the peak voltage across the speaker to half of the supply voltage.  If you wanted the speaker to see +12 V and -12 V you would need a FULL bridge.

Think of the transistors as variable resistors. When Q1 is 0 ohms and Q2 is infinite, you get +V out. When Q1 is infinite and Q2 is zero ohms, you get -V out. Other ratios will give you intermediate voltages, but you can never get a voltage outside the range of +V to -V.

@JohnD " but then the capacitor's average voltage would be half the supply limiting the peak voltage across the speaker to half of the supply voltage" so it is the capacitor what "split" the voltage?   "If you wanted the speaker to see +12 V and -12 V you would need a FULL bridge" am trying to understand very well half bridge topology.

@Mattman944 i know that transistors are electronics switcher means it is conducting or inerumpting a potentiel. Let me ask you a question when the Q1 is open non conducting what are the Q2 is conducting? Because be the ammateurs/ hobbysits we imagine the traject of current every time we are looking at a circuit and its behaviour.

Short answer
Think of the output stage of the amplifier as a voltage divider. Consider all possible options for:

powering the divider,
grounding the load, and
connecting it to the divider's output.

CircuitLab experiments
This is only a specific circuit implementation, but behind it there are basic ideas (concepts) that we should understand. I propose to do it through highly simplified DC equivalent circuits.
In these conceptual schematics, we can represent the load RL with a voltmeter to monitor the voltage across it. But since usually the load has a relatively low resistance (for example, 1 kΩ) and consumes current, we can set such an internal resistance to the voltmeter and denote it by RL. Figuratively speaking, this will be a "visualized resistor load" RL.
To see the current, hover the mouse over some of the devices.
Voltage sources
The simplest way to represent the amp output stage (the two transistors supplied by the DC source) is by a varying DC voltage source Vout that can vary its voltage from zero to 10 V. Here I have assumed that the voltage changes linearly in order to use the CircuitLab DC Simulation. In your circuit, the voltage is pulsed, but this difference is not essential for the answer to your main question, why the voltage on the load does not change to the supply voltage. Finally, we may consider this case as well.
So, the load has two terminals and you want to apply (and change) the voltage between them (across the load). It is easiest to fix the voltage of one terminal - 0, 5 or 10 V, for example.
Load to ground: Let's first connect the load (the black voltmeter probe) to ground.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So in this initial case, the voltage across the load is positive and varies linearly from 0 to 10 V.

Load to V+: But the ground is a relative concept. So we can connect the right load terminal (the black voltmeter probe) to any point, e.g. the maximum voltage V+ (10 V).

simulate this circuit
Now the voltage across the load is negative and varies linearly from -10 V to 0 V. This is because the V+ voltage is subtracted from Vout (in series fashion, in the loop Vout - V+ - VL) and the result is a negative voltage across the load.

Load to V+/2: Let's finally connect the right load terminal to the middle (5 V) of the  maximum voltage V+ (10 V).

simulate this circuit
When Vout varies from 0 V to 5 V, the voltage across the load is negative, and varies linearly from -5 V to 0 V. Then, when  Vout varies from 5 V to 10 V, the  load voltage is positive and varies linearly from 0 V to 5 V.

So, if you choose 5 V, and change the voltage of the other terminal in the entire range 0 ÷ 10 V, the difference applied to the load will change from -5 V to 5 V. Thus we have obtained a bipolar output within the limits of the supply voltage.
Potentiometers
In electronic devices, the voltage source Vout is usually implemented by two regulating devices (transistors) connected in a voltage divider configuration ("half bridge"). They change their "resistance" in the opposite direction (complement each other). We can model this with a potentiometer P supplied by the voltage V+. Now we can repeat the experiments above by linearly moving the wiper up. Thus we linearly increase the potentiometer's transfer ratio K = r2/(r1 + r2) from 0 to 1.
Load to ground corresponds to Schematic 1.1 above.

simulate this circuit

Load to V+ corresponds to Schematic 1.2.

simulate this circuit

Load to V+/2 corresponds to Schematic 1.3. We can use the same 1 kΩ potentiometer P2 with K = .5 (the wiper is set in the middle). This configuration is a prelude to the full bridge at the end.

simulate this circuit

Split supply
To get a bipolar output in the above schematic, we "raised" the right end of the load by 5 V. But we can achieve the same effect if we "drop" the left end of the load. For this purpose, we need another but negative voltage source V- of -5 V. This connection of two sources in series is known as a "split supply". The name comes from the fact that, figuratively speaking, we have "split" a 10 V source in two. Note that the overall voltage is as above 5 + 5 = 10 V.

simulate this circuit
Vout and VL change within the limits of this voltage.

OP's circuit
This idea is further developed as an AC version in the OP's circuit where the two voltage sources are replaced by charged capacitors C+ and C-. Their capacitance is large enough so that they fail to significantly change their charge when the load current flows through them. To explore them in a DC fashion, in the conceptual circuit below I have replaced them by voltage sources (batteries). Note that they have some low internal resistance to avoid short circuiting.

simulate this circuit

In this application, Vout is pulsed between the two extreme values:
Vout = 10 V

simulate this circuit
Vout = 0 V

simulate this circuit
Full bridge
To make the voltage across the load change from -10 V to 10 V, we can apply a clever trick - instead of keeping the voltage of the right load end fixed, we can change it simultaneously and in the opposite direction.
Figuratively speaking, the ground becomes mobile and "moves" in the opposite direction.
We can model this trick in the conceptual Schematic 2.3 by moving the potentiometer wipers in the opposite direction.
Vout1 = 10 V, Vout2 = 0 V: For example, if you raise the P1 wiper to V+, I drop the P2 wiper to ground.

simulate this circuit
Vout1 = 0 V, Vout2 = 10 V: And vice versa, if you drop the P1 wiper to ground, I raise the P2 wiper to V+.

simulate this circuit
Let's now realize what we are actually doing with this trick. By reversing the right  terminal with 5 V, we are actually adding 5 V to the initial 5 V voltage change of the left terminal. This is because the two voltages applied to the load terminals are subtracted in series fashion in the loop (which acts as a subtractor). So, when the right voltage changes in the opposite direction, it is actually inverted and the subtractor becomes an adder.
Or more figuratively speaking, the voltage on the right load end assists the voltage on the left end in its desire to change the voltage across the load.
Enhancement
I have also created an enhanced version of this answer in dialog with artificial intelligence.

The question was closed as "This question needs to be more focused. It is not currently accepting answers". I honestly don't know what the policy is on this but, by proceeding to greatly expand a brief 5-line list answer into a very long answer, it does read like you're disregarding that closure. I would have expected the answer to be left 'as was' until the question is re-opened. Otherwise, surely it's (effectively) answering a question that the community elected not to answer.

@TonyM, I think there's no problem. With this series of illustrations without captions, I've simply given the OP something to think about.

It's a pov, but I think you can see my point that the community elected for something different. Otherwise, surely some of the OPs out there could make no further effort with their question if it's shown they'll get assistance anyway. Help isn't necessarily always helpful.

@TonyM, I understand and you are right. Your reasoning in the comments is very interesting. But I have to admit, I am very little interested in the pedagogical side of things anymore. All my life I've taught people who don't want to learn (circuits) and it's worn me out.  Now I enjoy the freedom to think only about my favorite circuit ideas and do not want to enter into human relationships. It's not very calm here, I see you're excited too...

... But maybe what makes us stay here is the constantly popping up OP's questions that make us think about things we didn't have time for before. Thanks for your selfless participation.

@Circuitfantasist let start with 1.1 it shows a voltmeter i guess reading 5v and Vout but no power source i dont get it

@Tintin, I'm glad you're interested.  As far as I understand, your idea is to trace the circuit evolution step by step in pictures? If so, I have already taken the first step and look forward to your comments.

@Circuitfantasist not exactly to be honnest  i started to believe that the half bridge topology is just a PWM clamper circuit nothing more.

@Tintin, the idea is much more general and applies to many other devices such as power supplies, analog amplifiers (as you asked your question by the way), etc. This is actually the principle of relative ground. I was going to look at it dialogically in this scenario because you said you're a hobbyist and want to understand circuits; but if you don't care, no problem.

@Circuitfantasist i didnt said i dont care i apologize to you, i want to know why its not swinging 12 <=> -12 since it use two mosfets and power supply 12v. I just didnt want to make it harder to you thats all sorry again

@Tintin, ok, here's an intuitive verbal explanation: The load has two terminals and you want to apply (and change) the voltage between them (across the load). It is easiest to fix the voltage of one terminal - 0, 6 or 12 V. If you choose 6 V, and change the voltage of the other terminal in the entire range 0 ÷ 12 V, the difference applied to the load will change from -6 V to 6  V. To be able to change it from -12 V to 12 V, you can apply a clever trick - instead of keeping the first terminal fixed, you can change it simultaneously and in the opposite direction (the bridge idea)...

Figuratively speaking, the ground becomes mobile in the opposite direction, or so is the differential idea. Thus, the voltage across  the load will change from -12 V to 12 V. This is what I wanted to tell you step by step in my "picture scenario" .

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You've sure misread me for excitement and I'll try to live up to a bit of selflessness :-) You're relishing the long learner discussions so, yep, chat's your way forward. Have a good one...

@TonyM, What a team we can make if we come together... and everyone will benefit from it...

Thank you Cyril

@Circuitfantasist, "everyone will benefit from it" Except me and you :-) You'd drive me mad with your multi-page "now once upon a time..." essay answers and I'll irritate the life out of you with my shorter stuff you'll think has got 90% of anything worth reading missing. But I do appreciate the friendly sentiment and wish you well as always (raises imaginary pint glass and waves imaginary salt'n'vinegar crisps in your imaginary direction :-D ).

@TonyM, thank you for sharing.  As you may have guessed, as an older person who has suffered a lot in life, I pursue in addition to knowledge and a definite educational purpose with my answers. With these short introductory stories from my life (I am not anonymous) I want to show that, apart from a purposeful search for benefit from this activity, there were and are people who do it out of inner necessity...

... While I was thinking hard about the ideas on which circuits were built, and exploring them with my students in the lab, my colleagues at the university were accumulating publications for their habilitation. Yes, my story is long, but I would say it is meaningful. All schematics are "live" and can be experimented with. They are arranged to show the logic of the circuit solution development. With them I show a different way of using the simulator. And notice that I don't hide anything, I share it with everyone (for which I often get "-1")...

Just to clarify that my comment was about my latest answer (but it also applies to this one and in general).

@TonyM, Here is my reply to your subtle British humor composed by my friend and native English speaker Gemini at my request-:) "Thanks for the feedback, TonyM! I appreciate your honesty and your sense of humor. I guess we're just two sides of the same coin: you like your answers short and sweet, and I like mine long and detailed. But that's what makes the world interesting, right? The diversity of thought and opinion. So let's raise a glass to our differences and keep on sharing our knowledge with the world, in our own unique ways. Cheers!"

(You might remember us talking this over before.) I had years learning practical engineering and business in a large company, from/with a real mix of people and disciplines, designing/working medium-volume prod'n. I recall so many stand-out experiences of people who could express an idea or explanation in a few words or a longer description that was easy to recall and brought it to life. Getting that balance of vivid, useful and succinct gives them the building blocks to digest, to use later when ready to explore deeper stuff. Give them the whole subject and you lose them before you start.

So its a pov but one that's paid off a lot in life and that I've enjoyed passing on; I've worked with other learners over the many years and get on well with them. An important element is that the explanation has to be composed for what the listener needs, never because the answerer wants to enjoy saying it. In the latter, that way lies pain for all, we've all met them and struggled to get away! Have a great day and thanks for the translation, made me chuckle :-D
